# nHibernate Many-to-Many and Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, database, hibernate, nhibernate, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many association. The tables are as follows in my DB: `Event`, `Customer` & `Customer_Event`.

In the Event mapping file I have mapped the association with a cascade value of `"all-delete-orphan"`.

This works perfectly when adding a new record and it also works when deleting a record *(if the customer is not associated to another event)*. However when a customer is associated with multiple events I receive the following exception: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint.

This makes sense but I was wondering if its possible to do the following:

Delete an event and automatically delete the customer associations (i.e. records in the `Customer_Event` table) and if the `Customer` is not associated to another event also delete it. (i.e. from the `Customer` table)

This is the mapping I have in my Event.hbm.xml file:

```
<bag name="CustomerList" table="Customer_Event" inverse="false" 
                                                cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="EventId"/>
  <many-to-many class="Customer" column="CustomerId" />
</bag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this condition before delete action or just put one more catch in your delete method.

If you have a business rule,  put it in your application.  Databases are for data storage,  mostly.

Comment: The purpose of the "all-delete-orphan" cascading option is to do exactly that?

Comment: Yes,  exactly.  But in your case you have one(other?)  parent,  so your database notify you about it. Make sense what I'm saying?

Comment: Maybe if you create a link class to Customer_Event it can works.